# Compare and loop array index with previous and next array value

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I am looping through an array but I am having some trouble at first and last items in the array.

The code compares `arr[i]` with `arr[i+1]` and `arr[i-1]`. Obviously I want the index to compare `i-1` as the last element but this causes an out of bound array index.

Current Loop:

```
     (i=1; i<arr.size-1; i++) 

    if (arr(i-1,0)==2 || arr(i+1,0)==2)
    {
        do stuff
    }
```

It only works if `i` starts at `i=1` and loops to `arr.size-1`. How can I get around this?

Comment: What is the `variable`?? Is it a *real* variable, or a function?

Comment: It depends on your usage of the array. You could try and loop on the other "side" of the array (compare `arr[arr.size]` with `arr[array.size-1]` and `arr[0]` )

Comment: your code doesn't make sense, post all of your code. then maybe we can help.

Comment: Handle one edge case, loop from 1 to size-1, handle the other edge case. Wrap "do stuff" in a function so you don't need to duplicate it.

Comment: This isn't your full code - where is your loop?
What is "Variable" - is it a function? If so, then post that too.

Comment: Or, add two items to the array - duplicate the last item at 0 (shifting the arrray to the right), duplicate the first item at the end, and consider your array to start at 1 (or use the pointer `&arr[1]` and index from 0).

Comment: Assuming that this forms part of some algorithm, what are the boundary conditions (i.e. what does the algorithm say about how the first and last elements should be handled)? Are they special cases?

Comment: variable should read arr, unfortunately I cant post the full code. I am looping through with  for (i=1; i<arr.size-1; i++) currently but this ignores the processing of the first and last array elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either add explicit checks for i==0 and i==arr.size-1, or use some math, something like this:

```
if (variable(i>0?i-1:arr.size-1,0)==2 || variable((i+1)%arr.size,0)==2)
```

Comment: this is wrong! you are checking for `i > 0` and if its not you use the first index! how do you know that the first index should be used if `i !> 0`. and another thing how can you answer a question without a reasonable understanding of what he is trying to do?

Comment: @DimaMaligin No, it's not wrong. If i>0, then the prev. index is used, if i==0, then the last (arr.size-1) index (and not the first as you wrote).
And I'm pretty sure I understand what he wants :)

Comment: my bad you are right. didn't noticed the comma there before the 0, that still dose not make your answer correct though.

Answer (score 1):

To have *circular* indexes, you may use modulus as: (for `i` in `[0..array.size[`)

```
if (variable((i - 1 + arr.size()) % arr.size(), 0) == 2
 || variable((i + 1) % arr.size(), 0) == 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way around this.
You are operating at the limits of your array and you have to make sure you do not work outside of the memory portion where your elements are.

Here are some code snippets that should illustrate the principal connection.

```
int i;
int a[ARR_MAX]; //a[0] to a[ARR_MAX-1]


for(i = 0; i < ARR_MAX; ++i)
{
    a[i-1] //is an error if i is 0
    a[i] //the usual way to access an array
    a[i+1] //is an error if i is (ARR_MAX-1)
}

for(i = 1; i < (ARR_MAX-1); ++i)
{
    a[i-1] //i does not start a 0
    a[i+1] //i is never (ARR_MAX-1)
}

for(i = 0; i < ARR_MAX; ++i)
{
    a[(i-1)%ARR_MAX] //is an error if i is 0
    a[i%ARR_MAX] //is irrelevant in this loop
    a[(i+1)%ARR_MAX] //is a[0] if i is (ARR_MAX-1)
}

for(i = 1; 1; ++i) // loops forever, i will get negative at some point
{
    a[i%ARR_MAX]//can never be an error, unless i is negative
    a[(i+n)%ARR_MAX]//can never be an error, unless i is negative
    a[(i-n)%ARR_MAX]//is an error for n > i
}
```

Applied to your case it may simply be correct to us start and stop the loop one element earlier.
I will refine this statement if you can give some details about your usecase.

Answer (score -1):

If the elements in your array are on positions i=0..arr.size-1, then you could use something like this: `if ((i>0 && variable(i-1,0)==2) || (i<arr.size-1 && variable(i+1,0)))`. If the i>0 returns false, then variable(i-1,0)==2 won't even be checked so it won't give you exception.

Comment: this doesn't answer the original question, because he wanted to 'wrap around' the array boundaries (so index -1 should be the last element for example)

Comment: this is wrong! if your condition is false you are not doing anything. how do you know if "nothing" should be done in that case? and another thing how can you answer a question without a reasonable understanding of what he is trying to do?